# An error occurred (BadRequestException) when calling the UpdateClusterConfiguration operation: One or more of the parameters are not valid

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have a MSK cluster running on aws which is created with a default configuration. But when I try to update the configuration using **aws kafka update-cluster-configuration** im getting the following error *when calling the UpdateClusterConfiguration operation: One or more of the parameters are not valid.* Im not sure which parameter is wrong. I checked the cluster-arn as well as the configuration arn. Both seems to be right.

aws-cli version 1.16.207

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got the answer after reading document carefully. The cluster version does not refer to kafka version but its the version which aws gives to the cluster. Got it after describing cluster